# Exchange 2003 WebDAV LastModified Issue

Tags: ios, exchange-server, webdav, last-modified

I'm having an issue with an Exchange 2003 WebDAV interaction and I'm hoping someone can enlighten me.  We have a calendar synchronization application that keeps a user's Exchange calendar up to date with the calendar built into my company's application.  This synchronization is based off of the "LastModified" property of the given calendar appointments in the WebDAV returns.

The problem is that if a user modifies an appointment on their iPad or iPhone (which is pretty common) it does not update the "LastModified" property of the appointment which makes it appear as if though the appointment doesn't need to be updated for our application.  If we modify the appointment directly in the OWA interface it is updated correctly.

Does anyone know why this would not be getting updated for device side updates or perhaps even another way that we can track appointment changes?  In our synchronization for Exchange 2007 and 2010 we are using the ChangeKey property but to my knowledge that does not exist in the Exchange 2003 WebDAV interface.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: After posting this I stumbled upon the fix.  There is another property in the appointments called LastModifiedTime which has a more accurate representation of when appointments are changed.  This worked for detecting the device side updates in case anyone else runs into this issue.